# Logout is not working in symfony 6.3 on prod server

Tags: php, symfony, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have a site on symfony 6.3. When I developed it locally on localhost in docker there was no problem. But as soon as I moved it to a purchased domain on the server, the problem appeared. The domain zone of my domain is .in.net, i.e. the domain looks like:

```
domain.in.net
```

The site has a login only through social networks. And the login works fine - I get the data from the social network, write it into the database and login the user. But the logout does not work in any way - I'm tormented for the second day. Here are my configs:
security.yaml

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        fetcher:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: fetcher
            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
            custom_authenticator:
                - App\Security\OAuth\GithubAuthenticator
                - App\Security\OAuth\FacebookAuthenticator
                - App\Security\OAuth\GoogleAuthenticator
                - App\Security\OAuth\InstagramAuthenticator
                - App\Security\OAuth\LinkedinAuthenticator
                - App\Security\OAuth\MicrosoftAuthenticator
                - App\Security\OAuth\YahooAuthenticator
            # entry_point: App\Security\OAuth\GithubAuthenticator

            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: team


            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:
            - ROLE_USER

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/dashboard/adminka, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/dashboard, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

It should be noted here that when going to the "app_logout" route (specified in path:) a redirect to the "team" route (specified in target:) occurs, but no unlogging occurs. The user remains logged in. But symfony intercepts the /logout path as it should.

I also tried adding: cookie_domain: domain.in.net to framework.yaml, but it didn't solve the problem.

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #csrf_protection: true
    http_method_override: false
    handle_all_throwables: true

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        handler_id: null
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax
        cookie_domain: domain.in.net # Here specify my domain name
        storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.native

    #esi: true
    #fragments: true
    php_errors:
        log: true

when@test:
    framework:
        test: true
        session:
            storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.mock_file
```

I also noticed that if I clear the browser cache, I can log in and then log out of the account correctly. But if I log in again after that, I can't log out again.
When switching to /logout, the session remains in cookie, although it redirects to the route specified in target: team.
Is this a bug in symfony?

Comment: Please post the part of your controller that includes the app_logout route

Comment: Additionally provide the relevant output of bin/console debug:router

Comment: Additional add a log of your network requests during logout. Social (oauth2) login is built to login automatically (since you are logged in in that social account). Some social providers do not ask the user a second time if app-x is allowed to access user data.  But that's only the case if your login redirects you automatically. 
Also make sure the required cookies or session data is removed during logout.